# Is it possible to place the Intercom Messenger in the bottom left?

Tags: intercom, intercom.js

By default the Intercom Messenger appears at the bottom right of the page. How do I configure it to sit on the bottom left instead?

Comment: Wondering the same thing...

Answer (score 4):

You can change the position of the messenger by adding a key : value field to the intercomSettings called `'alignment' : 'left'` example:

```
window.intercomSettings = {
            app_id: "your_app_id",
            "alignment": 'left'
        };
```

You can also add paddings.
If you need more information go to -> https://docs.intercom.com/faqs-and-troubleshooting/the-intercom-messenger/can-i-move-the-messengers-position-on-my-product-or-site

Comment: Is there any way to change it programmatically after it's been initialized? For example, a right mounted sidebar that pushes it over as it comes out?